# How to move directory from one folder to another if directory modified year is not equal to current year?

Tags: php

I want to move folders & files to another folder, if the folder & file last modified date is not equal to current year.

Comment: your acceptance record is questionable

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry I didn't get you?

Answer (score -1):

See Php [stat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) to access to the time of last modification.

See Php [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to compare the last modification year to the current year

And see Php [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) to move your files or folder

You have everything in hand to solve your problem.

Comment: It displays time. I want to fetch date of the file.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh sorry, I was trying to give him the main directions without coding his project....

Comment: @Vyko I used rename function and it works, but the files are moving to the .gitignore folder. why files are moving to .gitignore folder?